# Validity of Bootstrap Inference for Bounds

Tags: bootstrap, bounds, two-sample

I am facing the following problem: I have access to iid $X_1,\dots ,X_{N_X}$ and $Y_1, \dots, Y_{N_Y}$ from $F_X$ and $F_Y$, respectively, where $X$ stochastically dominates $Y$.

My goal is to conduct inference on the following two functionals, which I have already shown to bound a quantity of interest $\theta$:
$$\theta_L = \int_p^{F_X^{-1}(F_Y(p))} (X-p)dF_X$$
(the light blue area in the figure) [image: figure1] and
$$\theta_U = \Big( \frac{F_Y(p)-F_X(p)}{F_X(q)-F_X(p)}\Big)\int_p^q (X-p)dF_X$$

(again, see the next figure for a visual representation) [image: figure2]

I am trying to prove that the naive bootstrap is valid in this case, at least if the marginals are continuous and satisfy weak regularity conditions.

I am trying to follow similar results that show bootstrap validity for quantiles (excluding maxima and minima) and L-statistics. For example I am looking at Chapter 3 in Politis and Romano (1990) and Chapter 3 of Shao and Tu (1995) but I cannot map my problem into their examples exaclty, and I am struggling to use their results.

I'd appreciate any insights, guidance, or suggestions on how to approach this, if anyone has experience with similar non-standard inference problems.